# Can't get php mail() to work

Tags: php, apache, email, mamp

I've got Mamp running on my mac and trying to get mail() to work.

This is what I've got to work with.

```
$to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'The subject!';
$message = 'Hi there!';


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
$headers .= 'From: Test <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{ print 'success!'; }
else
{ print 'fail!'; }

?>
```

It just keeps on returning false. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Some settings with php/apache I need to check?

Comment: it is not even getting to the mail function? or is it returning 'fail'?

Comment: you have to set up SMTP server

Comment: ... or just use SwiftMailer or similar so you can take advantage of features you will likely need, such as HTML e-mail, without the hassle of manually hacking MIME headers.  Then, connections to external SMTP servers are readily available as well,

Comment: The mailfunction is returning false.

Comment: Would you consider configuring an smtp server difficult? Any good link/guide?

Comment: i just tried your code and its working fine on my side, are you using this snippet on localhost?

Comment: Localhost for the moment. Do I have to put it on a server instead?

Comment: of-course php mail() function needs to be on sever if you want it to work. on localhost you always get fail! further there are setting for sending mail while on localhost but i think right now your are looking  your code gonna work!

Comment: Well, put it on my server and now it's apparently working. Getting true from mail(), that is. Still no mail recieved though.

Comment: ok which email address are you sending mail? if its gmail try find you mail in spam. if not so then try some other mailing servers yahoo and hotmail for testing purpose

Comment: Yeah, it's Gmail. No spam found. Tried my @me.com adress as well. No mail recieved.

Comment: if you getting "true" its mean your mail function is working only issue with receiving right, Check there are no email filters at your end, and found this link useful: http://formtoemail.com/support/not_receiving_email.php

Comment: Fiddled a bit with the headers, and now it's le working! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using your snippet on localhost, put on server and then try.
php mail() function needs to be on sever if you want it to work. on localhost you always get fail!

Comment: Unless you have a PHP client installed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$Name = "Da Duder"; //senders name
$email = "email@adress.com"; //senders e-mail adress
$recipient = "PersonWhoGetsIt@emailadress.com"; //recipient
$mail_body = "The text for the mail..."; //mail body
$subject = "Subject for reviever"; //subject
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields

ini_set('sendmail_from', 'me@domain.com');

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
?>
```

http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

each line of text may not be bigger than 70 chars and needs to be cut off with a LF (\n)

EDIT: as @brad suggested: SwiftMailer is realy good!

Comment: I'm lookin into Swift at the moment.